# css - Unsupported CSS Property Transparency in codename1

Tags: css, codenameone

I am getting following exception in codename1

`CSS> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported CSS property Transparency`

Code used by me is as follow :-

`Form {
    Background Color: 0xffffff;
    Transparency: 255;
}`

What should I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Form {
    Background Color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

or

Form {
    Background Color: transparent;
}
```

One of theses three should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color to a value using:

```
background-color: #ffffff;
```

Opacity is implicit when you define it this way. You can use transparency using:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: This issue occurred when I were trying to execute examples of "Create Uber clone in 7 days". What should I use in case of other transparency values ?

Comment: These values aren't css. They use the syntax declared in the book. Notice that the book uses an abstract syntax explained in the 2nd chapter

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background transparency along with the color name

```
form{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);}
```

RGBA stands for Red Green Blue Alpha. Here the `Alpha` defines the transparency.
You can set the `0.3` to `0` to make it completely transparent.

Try this

You can learn more about transparency here:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

Answer (score 0):

if css is the same in java then the correct syntax would be:

```
Form {
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: opacity(0.5);
}
```

the filter property should be between 0 and 1 where 0 is 0% and 1 is 100%

Comment: getting following `CSS> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported CSS property Filter`. I tried with `filter` as well.

Comment: maybe you could avoid a second property by using the rgba color system for the background. Example: background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) This would be red color with a 50% oppacity (The last Value is the oppacity). So setting it to 0 would result in a completely transparent background.